# Can't remove U.S. from the languages and input methods menu

Tags: keyboard, language, input-source

I wonder if I can remove the U.S. language of the languages list.
Because I use a shortcut to cycle through input methods, and don't want to land on U.S. as *ArgenPinYin* is already a modified U.S. international keyboard layout, so I don't need the plain U.S.
Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: Which OS version?

Comment: 10.6.8 _____________________________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that OS X requires a keyboard layout that it recognizes as producing latin characters to be selected as one of the choices in the menu, and it does not recognize ArgenPinYin as one of them. I can deselect the US layout if I select German or Portuguese, for instance, but not if I select Greek or Pinyin - Simplified.

So yes, U.S. can be removed as a language, but some other keyboard layout that OS X recognizes as a Latin layout must first be selected.

Comment: I used "Ukelele" to create a custom layout, but it's set to "Roman", but I still can't delete US :(

Comment: How does one get OS X to recognize ones own layout, then?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

OS X might recognize a custom layout as equivalent to one of the Roman system layouts if you could somehow include it in the AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle in system/library/keyboard layouts, but I have never seen any way to modify that.